# Expression Engine: Category Group Name

Tags: html, content-management-system, expressionengine

Does anyone know how to get the category group name in EE? So something like this...

`{categories}{category_group_name}: {category_name}{/categories}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use the query module, but it's a quickie:

```
{categories}
    {exp:query sql="SELECT group_name FROM exp_category_groups WHERE group_id = '{category_group}'"}{group_name}: {/exp:query}
    {category_name}
{/categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your best bet is probably a plugin. It doesn't seem that there's a native way to do this.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-group-name/

Comment: This plugin will list all category groups, but can't grab an individual group name based on its group_id.